# Window does not show view when clicking command in menu item - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, command

I have been trying to solve this issue for a few hours now. Basically, I have WPF window that has a menu item. Once you click that item, it should a grid with 2 views (one on the left and one on the right).

The problem here is that when I click that menu item, nothing happens. I checked all my commands and the visibility and all. I have even checked the web trying to find a solution but found nothing that made it work.

Hopefully I can get some insight to my issue.

Here is my App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="BoekBeheer.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer.WpfApp.Views"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer.WpfApp.ViewModels"
         StartupUri="/Views/BoekBeheerAppView.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Styles-->

    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}"></Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type FrameworkElement}}" x:Key="ViewModelBorder">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--Data templates-->

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BoekViewModel}">
        <views:BoekenView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BoekListViewModel}">
        <views:BoekListView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:BoekDetailViewModel}">
        <views:BoekDetailView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    
</Application.Resources>
```

Here is my view with the menu items BoekBeheerAppView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="BoekBeheer.WpfApp.Views.BoekBeheerView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer.WpfApp.Views"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer.WpfApp.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:BoekBeheerViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          >
        <MenuItem Header="Bestand"
                  >
            <MenuItem Header="Afsluiten"
                      Command="{Binding AfsluitenCommand}"
                      ></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Beheer"
                  >
            <MenuItem Header="Boeken"
                      Command="{Binding BoekBeheerCommand}"
                      ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Auteurs"
                      Command="{Binding AuteurBeheerCommand}"
                      ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Uitgevers"
                      Command="{Binding UitgeverBeheerCommand}"
                      ></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentBeheerViewModel}"
                    ></ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Here is my view that connects 2 other view to display in a grid BoekBeheerView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BoekBeheer.WpfApp.Views.BoekView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BoekBeheer.WpfApp.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ViewModelBorder}"
            Grid.Column="0">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentBoekListViewModel}"></ContentControl>
    </Border>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ViewModelBorder}"
            Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentBoekDetailViewModel}"></ContentControl>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try to set DataContext in code behind in constructor of MainWindow, maybe this would help